# How do I create a POST request with form field content with Spray?

Tags: scala, specs2, spray

I've got a Spray service that expects a POST with certain form fields filled out. I'm trying to work out how to create an appropriate POST in my test spec in order to test this.

What I have so far

```
  Post("/customer") ~> sealRoute(myRoute) ~> check {
    responseAs[String] must contain("Success message")
  }
```

Which does a POST to the /customer route, as expected. How do I add form fields to this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`spray.http.FormData`](http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/api/index.html#spray.http.FormData) class:

```
Post("/customer", FormData(Seq("field1"->"value1", "field2"->"value2")) ~>
  sealRoute(myRoute) ~> check {
    responseAs[String] must contain("Success message")
  }
```

Comment: Doesn't compile with `could not find implicit value for parameter ta: MyControllerSpec.this.TildeArrow[spray.routing.RequestContext,Unit]
  Post("/customer", FormData(Seq("field1"->"value1", "field2"->"value2"))) ~> sealRoute(sso.route) ~> check {^`

Comment: `Post("/", FormData(Map("foo" -> "bar"))) ~> route ~> check` works for me